# Determine Virtual Machine status and activity in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I have an account with Azure and different subscriptions with different Resource Group and different virtual machine. I would like to know how I can determine which ones are unused. For example check the last date where the virtual machine was started or used by the user using a powershell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PowerShell Method**

Within PowerShell you can use the following command to query the VM API.

You want to look at the Provisioning Status and Time, as well as the Running Status:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

Get-AzureRmVm | Get-AzureRmVm -Status | select ResourceGroupName, Name, @{n="Provisioned Time"; e={$_.Statuses[0].Time}}, @{n="Provisioned Status"; e={$_.Statuses[0].DisplayStatus}}, @{n="Running Status"; e={$_.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus}}
```

This will give the following output

```
ResourceGroupName  : RG-Name
Name               : VM-Name
Provisioned Time   : 27/06/2018 19:06:39
Provisioned Status : Provisioning succeeded
Running Status     : VM deallocated

ResourceGroupName  : RG-Name1
Name               : VM-Name1
Provisioned Time   : 27/06/2018 19:06:39
Provisioned Status : Provisioning succeeded
Running Status     : VM running
```

**REST API Method**

Outside of PowerShell you can do this relatively easily using a couple of API calls:

Use the VM API to get a listing of all of your VMs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall

Then call the Instance View API to retreive the last known Instance Status of the VM

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/instanceview#instanceviewstatus

This will give you the same set of statuses as in the PowerShell method above. The `InstanceViewStatus` that contains the `Status` and the `Time` of the last state of the machine.

Here is the sample JSON of the status part of the returned response for one of my VMs:

```
  "statuses": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "time": "2017-06-15T13:59:26.8578303+00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "PowerState/running",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "VM running"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: So you are suggesting I should do it on the azure portal ?

Comment: Have updated to have a powershell method to do the same

Answer (score 1):

Run query in Azure Resource Graph Explorer:

```
Resources
| project name, location, 
   PowerState=tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code), type
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| order by name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can check the VM status through the resource group one by one. Or all the VM status in one subscription. But not all the vm belongs to you. So I suggest you check through the resource group one by one which belongs to you. And the PowerShell script like below:

```
# connect to Azure with your account
Connect-AzureRmAccount

# get all the subscriptions of yours in this account
Get-AzureRmSubscription

# select which subscription you want to check
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId yourSubscriptionId

# get the power status of the vm in one resource group
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName yourResourceGroupName -Status
```

The output like this:
[image]

For more details, see [`Get-AzureRmVM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/get-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.9.0).