# Azure VM start/stop logs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[image]We have multiple Virtual Machine's in our azure infrastructure.Can someone please let me how can I get the logs of Azure Virtual Machine start/stop time and by whom it was done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always go to [View Activity Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/view-activity-logs) and see the activity.

If you want to check the status and the activity you can do it through Powershell or REST API as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481983/determine-virtual-machine-status-and-activity-in-microsoft-azure)

**`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/instanceView?api-version=2019-12-01`**

Comment: I checked, there is no activity logs for me but my vm was started and stopped.

Comment: how do you say so?

Comment: Sorry I had overlooked, Now I found the activity logs in Monitor service. Thanks alot.