# Azure alert reboot vm on status busy

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, alert

I am trying to monitor VM status.
I have activated logs, and trying to query the status of the VM.
I can not find the status or health status.

Answer (score 0):

**In order to query the status of Azure VMs, make use of below PowerShell commands:**

- Use the **- Status** parameter to check whether the VMs are running, deallocated, or stopped using PowerShell like below:

```
Get-AzVM -Status | Select name, powerstate, provisioningState
```

[image]

- If you want to get Status of **particular VM** then use the below PowerShell command:

```
Get-AzVM -Name "YourVmName" -ResourceGroup "YourResourceGroupName" -status
```

[image]

- If you want to query the status of Azure VMs from **Azure Resource Graph Explorer** make use of below:

```hs
Resources  
| project name, location,  
PowerState=tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code), type  
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'  
| order by name desc
```

Please note that there is no such state called **"Busy"**, check this **[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/states-billing#power-states-and-billing).**

For more information, please find below **references**:

[powershell - Determine Virtual Machine status and activity in Microsoft Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481983/determine-virtual-machine-status-and-activity-in-microsoft-azure)

[How to check Azure VM Power state using PowerShell? (tutorialspoint.com)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-azure-vm-power-state-using-powershell)

Comment: Thank you, But all that I can do. What I need is to check it in an alert via a signal.

Comment: **AFAIK**, there is no [signal](https://i.imgur.com/oXr3N7y.png) available to check Azure VM status. If your VM is unavailable, you can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/tutorial-monitor-vm-alert)  if helpful as an workaround !