# How to get the list of the unused Azure Resources from the portal/powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am working to delete the unused azure resources which are not used since last 3 months to save the cost.
I tried to find in internet but not getting the proper answer.

Is any one know how to get the list though powershell or can export the details from the azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or can export the details from the azure portal?

Yes, you can get the status of Vms as it is deallocated or not by using Azure resource graph as below and i followed [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014666/17623802) as below:

> ```
> Resources
>         | project name, location,     PowerState=tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code),
>         type
>         | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
>         | order  by name desc
> ```

[image]

As you asked that you want Vms  if its not used in 3 months by using Azure log Analytics Worksapce query and followed [M-QandA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/786232/query-to-get-the-last-active-time-of-a-resourcedis.html) as below:

> ```
> AzureActivity
>  |  where  TimeGenerated  >= ago(90d)
> |  where  _ResourceId contains "Microsoft.Compute/disks"  or  _ResourceId contains "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
> | distinct _ResourceId
> ```

Answer (score 1):

"Unused" means a lot of different things when you look at different resource types. Maybe you are looking for VMs which are deallocated? Or for a SQL DB which had zero per cent CPU util? Or....

So, there is no general way to determine this through the ARM APIs.

Comment: Hi @silent, Thanks,  Got Your point. It also helps if it's for VM only. Currently, I am going to each VM and checking the activity logs for the last 3 months. If there is no activity then I am deleting that VMs. So looking at any command or script which gets the VMs which are not been used for the last 3 months whether it is in start mode or deallocated mode.