# How can I check the state of over 200 VM's in Azure?

Tags: azure

To display the state (Running, Deallocated etc) of our VM's, I currently use the following command and this works fine.

`az vm list -o table -d -g  ....`

With the number of VM's increasing on a regular basis, this is getting very cumbersome. For 200 VM's, I need to run this command 200 times.

Is there an easier way to obtain this information, by querying GraphAPI maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and Thanks to @volody, followed his [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014666/17623802) and below is the query to run in Azure Resource Graph explorer:

> ````
>       Resources
>         | project name, location,
>         PowerState=tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code),
> type
>         | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
>         | order  by name desc ```
> ````

[image]

References taken from:

- [powershell - Determine Virtual Machine status and activity in Microsoft Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481983/determine-virtual-machine-status-and-activity-in-microsoft-azure/65014666#65014666)

**Edit 2:**

***Yes you can get different vms using names as below:
I used has :***

***| where name has "x" or name has "y"***

[image]

Comment: How do I limit it for the VM's (say 200) that I am interested in ?

Comment: Hey @souser I have edited my answer according to your requirement, I have kept 10 you can use 200 over there.

Comment: Let me clarify, I have say 1000 VM's in my subscription and I want to list the status for only 200 VM's. How do I specify these 200 VM's in the query ?

Comment: Do you want to list first 200? or do you want to list which have names or any property in common?

Comment: List the status of 200 VM's individually by their hostnames

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your requirement , I have displayed 3 Vms using HostNames and in the same way you can do it for 200 Vms

Comment: the 200 VMs that you are interested in, do they have any common value/text in their names? are they all in a particular RG?

Comment: @wonderwall, they are in specific subscription

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "--query" parameter to get the names of VMs which have a particular text in names(At the start). The ! is ignoraing the VMs which names start with 'E2E'.

```
$vmsinrg=$(az vm list -g $resourcegroup --query "[?!starts_with(name,'E2E')].{ VMName:name }") | Convertfrom-json
```

There are other conditions as well which are taken by --query.
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts%2Cbash][1]

If you do not have some naming rules which you can use to get the names of those 200 VMs then you need to think about using a naming convention as you cant do any thing except do them manually.

What you can also do is create the list one time, everytime you have a new VM add the new name to that list. import that list as an array and then run the command to get the status of each one at a time using a loop.