# Azure Virtual Machine Running Status

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

I want to know the running status of VM running in Azure(Windows Server). Using Azure CLI I can get the status which is same as "display status" using the command
`az vm get-instance-view --ids $vmsids[$w] --query instanceView.statuses[1].displayStatus | Convertfrom-json`
I have experienced that display status is not always correct. I thing it only tells you if the status of the VM is poweron or off. I need to know if the OS has all booted up and working fine.
I know I can look for a particular service and see if its running to make sure that the OS is up and running but I am after something which AZCLI gives.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce in my environment and got expected results as below:

**Using Azure Cli Commands and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest):**

```
az vm get-instance-view --name vmName --resource-group resourceGroupName --query instanceView.statuses[1] --output table
az vm show -n VMName -g VMRG --query "[storageProfile.imageReference]"
```

[image]

If you want to know about OS use below command:

```
az vm show -n VMName -g VMRG --query "[storageProfile.imageReference]"
```

[image]

To show each and every property of VM you can use below command:

```
az vm show -n VNName -g VMrg | fl *
```

[image]

**Uisng Azure Powershell commands and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-0.10.0):**

I want to get the display status (if its ready to use or not) of a particular VM i  used below command :

```
(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName  XX -Name YY -Status).VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus
```

XX- Name of Resource Group
YY- Name of the VM

[image]

If you want to know if VM is running or not you can use below command:

```
(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName  XX -Name YY -Status).Statuses.DisplayStatus
```

XX- Name of Resource Group
YY- Name of the VM

[image]

For complete status(os version, OS type) of VM use below command:

```
(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName  XX -Name YY -Status)
```

XX- Name of Resource Group
YY- Name of the VM

[image]

For further you can do it with resource graph explorer [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73736074/how-can-i-check-the-state-of-over-200-vms-in-azure/73740538#73740538) in my previous answer.

Comment: Not sure what you were trying to reproduce. My issue was that the "display status Running" does not always mean that the OS has been bootedup and running. One scenario is when the OS reboots for installing updates and after the restart installs the remaining updates. In this scenario the OS has not booted up completely, none of the OS services have started but the display status will show "Running". The other command that you showed is also showing the same status and I believe its not AZCLI command.

Comment: The second one is powershell command