# How to get Azure VM Creation Date, Modification Date and Created by and Modified by using Azure Powershell for a subscription?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I want to export the report of Azure VMs to group VMs based on created by and modified by to take further actions on it. Microsoft doesn't provide logs for >90 days created VMs.

Comment: Did you try Get-AzDisk cmdlet?

Comment: Yes, but it does not give Created by, Modified by and Modified Date Information, it only gives VM creation Date.

Answer (score 0):

To get Creation date and Created by you can use below command and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/resource-graph-samples?tabs=azure-cli) :

```
az graph query -q " Resources | project tags.CreatedDate,tags.CreatedBy, type | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'" |ft
```

[image]

To get all properties that have changed you can use below command:

```
az graph query -q " Resources | project properties , type | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'" |ft
```

[image]

If you are expecting to get to know the changes you can use below command and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes?tabs=azure-cli#run-your-resource-graph-query):

```
az graph query -q 'resourcechanges | project properties.changeAttributes.timestamp, properties.changeType, properties.targetResourceId, properties.targetResourceType, properties.changes | limit 5'
```

**Edit:**

Use below command to get name also:

```
az graph query -q " Resources | project name, tags.CreatedDate,tags.CreatedBy, type | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'" |ft
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get the VM name in the first command, and when I execute this command, field values created by and created date are returned as null.

Comment: @Yogesh Kulkarni, I have edited my answer according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm getting VM name But still getting "null" values for tags_CreatedBy and tags_CreatedDate. Not sure whats the reason.

Comment: Try to use the query in resource graph explorer([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73736074/how-can-i-check-the-state-of-over-200-vms-in-azure/73740538#73740538))

Comment: You can also use Microsoft Graph Api to get all details of Vm. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/get?tabs=HTTP)